# Cassandra JDBC interface

Tags: jdbc, interface, cassandra

I am trying to perform crud database operations on cassandra database,but eventually I came across a problem that cassandra jdbc driver requires predefined column family defination in the database, created using create columnfamily cql command.

More over the insert statement also fails if I try to insert a new column-value , other then specified in earlier create columnfamily statement.

I want to know if it is an usual behaviour or something going wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using cql,You have to first create the column definition .On second half It seems problem because it is possible to insert any key value at any time whether it is defined or not.
can you show code here so that i can trace the problem

Comment: Thanks sunil, you are right , it is possible to insert any column into column family. It was sure a bug in my code.